# Can't install rPython package in R

Tags: r

I'm using CentOS 6.4 and I'm trying to install the R package 'rPython'. It failed with following messages. Anybody knows how to fix this? Thanks!

```
/usr/bin/ld:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(dictobject.o): relocation     R_X86_64_32S against `PyDict_Type' can not be used when making a shared     object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a: could not read     symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rPython.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rPython’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/rPython’
```

Comment: see if adding `--enable-shared` helps

Comment: I tried `R CMD INSTALL --enable-shared rPython_0.0-5.tar.gz`. Still got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the default installation of Python on RHEL / CentOS,
etc. is not "shared enabled", i.e., it does not include libpython*.so. Just the libpython*.a static library. This prevents some Python
applications to run properly. There are instructions in different
places, (e.g., [here](http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/) or [here](https://www.fir3net.com/Programming/Python/how-do-i-compile-modwgsi-for-python-27.html)) indicating how to install Python as a shared library on CentOS and related Linux flavours.